# REST API call returning undefined list from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I'm attempting to display a  list of presidential candidate names from the FEC REST API on a website and am getting a list of three bulleted items that just say "undefined."

I've tried this with other APIs like https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films and it works perfectly. Something about the FEC structure of the JSON file is different - I'm not sure if reason for this JSON being treated differently is the pagination or something else.

Here are the first lines of the raw JSON:

```
    {
      "api_version": "1.0",
      "pagination": {
        "pages": 1,
        "per_page": 20,
        "page": 1,
        "count": 20
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "election_years": [
            2008,
            2016
          ],
          "two_year_period": 2020,
          "last_file_date": "2016-07-30",
          "federal_funds_flag": false,
          "name": "SANDERS, BERNARD"
      }
   }


$.getJSON("https://api.open.fec.gov/v1/candidates/totals/?office=P&election_full=false&per_page=20&cycle=2020&min_receipts=100000&sort_null_only=false&sort_nulls_last=false&page=1&sort_hide_null=false&api_key=MYKEYISHERE", 
function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        $('ul#candidates').append('<li>'+item.name+'</li>');
    });
```

});

```
    <body>
            <div class="cand-container">
                    <img class="photo">
                    <ul id="candidates"></p>
                    <p class="receipts"></p>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `console.log(data);` undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to loop through `data` when you should be looping through `data.results`

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thank you!